# Authentication encryption or server side verification

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, encryption

I have a set of public APIs that take in an id and some parameters.  Clients (could be browsers or mobile phones), each having their own `int` ids, can interact with these public APIs.  Of course, we don't want a situation where client changes his id and send a request screwing things up for other people thus, when authentication takes place, a `GUID` is sent to the client as an authentication token.  All subsequent request must include that authentication token.  On the server, the back end does a look up in the DB to match the `GUID` with the id.  If they match, the process can go forward otherwise UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown.  All works fine and dandy.

But of course, the problem is that every operation does a db look up.  I did some caching but then caching the authentication token has its own issues (tears tears).

One other way to do it is to encrypt something and pass it in the query string.  But then when the request comes in, I have decrypt the string to see if it's valid.  There is no free lunch there.

asp.net sets an encrypted cookie for authentication.  But the view state encrypts things in the hidden field.  The encrypted cookie doesn't work for me since I'm passing around JSON/SOAP (some clients send json some send xml).

If you actually read all the above, then thank you and I look forward to your input! Otherwise and for others, **the question is** , is there a "best-practice" around my dilemma?

Comment: Authenticated encryption by HMAC allows you to do a computationally less intensive hash rather than a decrypt to verify the sender and the integrity of the message (though you still need to decrypt the message to read it).  You have a shared secret key.  When they send you a message, they encrypt the message.  Then they concatenate it with a permutation of the secret key and hash it.  Then they concatenate that with a different permutation of the key and hash again.  They send this with the cipher text so you know who it's from and that it is not tampered with before decrypting it. See RFC2104

Comment: @WDS thank.  Will do.